# Read csv from previous 7 days in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have written a function to read files with specific wildcard and path from (like this one for example) previous seven days.

```
def i_get_last_week_file(self, par_path, par_file_wildcard, par_datetime):
    proc_datetime = par_datetime - timedelta(weeks=1)
    logger.info('Processing time: %s', str(proc_datetime))
    # file_list = []
    while proc_datetime <= par_datetime:
        sdate = proc_datetime.strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%H')
        for p_file in os.listdir(par_path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(p_file, par_file_wildcard + sdate + '*.csv'):
                self.files_list.append(p_file)
        break
    return self.files_list

def get_csv_from_local_weekly(self, par_path, par_wildcard_name, par_date=None, par_time=None):
    if par_date is None:
        par_date = self.file_date
    if par_time is None:
        par_time = self.file_time
    end_datetime = datetime.combine(par_date, par_time)
    a = self.i_get_last_day_file(par_path, par_wildcard_name, end_datetime)
    for i in a:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(par_path+''+i, index_col=None, header=0, delimiter=';')
            self.pandas_list.append(df)
        except Exception:
    frame = pd.concat(self.pandas_list)
    self.files_list = []
    self.pandas_list = []
    return frame
```

The problem is, read only the files that are exactly seven days old, but I need to collect all files from previous 7 days from today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to create a range of 7 days and this is one way of doing it:

```
import datetime
import re

td = datetime.datetime.today()

lastWeek = [(td - datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%H') for i in range(7)]

for p_file in os.listdir(par_path):
    dateSearch = re.search('\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}', pfile)
    if dateSearch:
        dateFound = dateSearch.group(0)
        if dateFound in lastWeek:
            ...
```

Of course, you can change the `td` into your date variable, I just used it for testing.

Also, your `proc_datetime` doesn't seem to increment inside the `while` loop, and if you introduce the increment - you won't need the `break`:

```
while proc_datetime <= par_datetime:
    sdate = proc_datetime.strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%H')
        for p_file in os.listdir(par_path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(p_file, par_file_wildcard + sdate + '*.csv'):
                self.files_list.append(p_file)
    proc_dateimte += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. :)